# How to create a flat menu structure with icons?

Tags: html, css

I have an unordered list like so...

```
<ul class="dangling-menu">
<li><i class="fa fa-trophy fa-2x full-line"></i>l1</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-cogs fa-2x full-line"></i>l2</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o fa-2x full-line"></i>l3</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-flask fa-2x full-line"></i>l4</li>
</ul>
```

I would like to make this list flat [side by side, i.e]. display:inline does it for me.

```
.dangling-menu{
    text-align:center;
    border-bottom:1px #e8e8e8 solid;
}
.dangling-menu li{
    list-style-type:none;
}
.full-line{
    display:block;
}
```

Almost everything is okay... except the li is vertical. I want the layout out be horizontal. Please assist.

This is how it looks like...

[image]

I want the icons to be adjacent to each other, but the text below should be as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `display: inline-block;` to your `.dangling-menu` class as follow:

```
.dangling-menu li{
    list-style-type:none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/e2aufjcc/1/

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
.dangling-menu li{
    list-style-type:none;
}
```

with

```
.dangling-menu li{
    list-style-type:none;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.dangling-menu{
    text-align:center;
    border-bottom:1px #e8e8e8 solid;
}
.dangling-menu li{
    list-style-type:none;
   display:inline-block;
  margin-right:10px;
}
.full-line{
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```